# React Native - ScrollView with scrolling text input at bottom

Tags: ios, react-native, scrollview

I'm working on a react native mobile application for iOS and trying to make an overlaying TextInput remain sticky at the bottom of a ScrollView. My first thought was to move it outside the ScrollView, and this works but does not allow for the overlay of the component over the scrolling content.

Here's a sample of my code:

basic idea:

    `<ScrollView style={styles.tabView}>
       <View>
       </View>
       <TextInput style={styles.input} />
    </ScrollView>`

I can only get it to do one of the following: 1) remain at bottom with no overlay and 2) only display at the bottom of the entire scroll view.

Is there a best of both worlds?

Any help at all with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap the ScrollView and the TextInput inside a container and then style the TextView to half transparent and position 'absolute' and stick it to the bottom of the container..

```
   <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>
     <View style={{height: 400, width: 400}}>                 
       <ScrollView>
         <View style={{backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
            // Your data here
         </View> 
      </ScrollView>
      <TextInput style={{backgroundColor: '#c4c4c4dd', position: 'absolute', bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0}} />
    </View>
  </View>
```

You can see [this example](https://rnplay.org/apps/cQmREw) which I've prepared for you. Enjoy.

Comment: If it satisfies your question, please vote up and mark as answer.  Thx :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1861047/atlanteh I set as answer. Excuse the delay it's been since my comp sci classes since I've used stack overflow. They won't let me upvote as I don't have the "reputation" yet.

Answer (score -1):

The best and easiest way is to use the following tag as your codes container:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
      behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
      style={{flex:1}}
    >
...
 </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```